Deep Linking Issue in Expo React Native: Redirecting to Incorrect Screen
I am developing a React Native app using Expo and have trouble with deep linking functionality. I have set up the configuration to handle deep links, but when I click on a link like myapp://updatepassword/:token, the app redirects to the PasswordResetScreen instead of the intended UpdatePasswordScreen.
I have double-checked the deep linking setup in both app.json and app.js, and tried rebuilding the app, but the issue persists. The UpdatePasswordScreen is correctly set up in the navigation stack, but the deep link does not navigate to it as expected.
I am a beginner with React Native and Stack Overflow, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!
What I Tried:

Configured deep linking in app.json and app.js.
Tested deep linking with a URL like myapp://updatepassword/<token>.

Expected Result:
The app should navigate to the UpdatePasswordScreen with the correct token.
Actual Result:
The app redirects to the PasswordResetScreen instead.
Code Samples frontEnd:
** app.json:**
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "android": {
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": {
            "scheme": "myapp",
            "host": "updatepassword"
          },
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

** App.js:**
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

import FlashMessage from "react-native-flash-message";

import { AuthProvider } from "./src/context/authContext";
import MainDrawerNavigation from "./src/navigation/DrawerNavigation/MainDrawerNavigation";

const prefix = Linking.createURL("myapp://");
const expoPrefix = "exp://192.168.1.101:8081";

const App = () => {
  const navigationRef = useRef(null);

  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix, expoPrefix],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Auth: {
          screens: {
            Login: "login",
            PasswordReset: "passwordReset",
            Signup: "signup",
            UpdatePassword: "updatepassword/:token",
          },
        },
        Decouvrir: {
          screens: {
            Discoveries: "discoveries",
            Detail: "detail/:id",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  function handleDeepLink(event) {
    const { url } = event;
    const parsed = Linking.parse(url);
    console.log("handleDeepLink", url);
    console.log("Parsed path:", parsed.path);
    console.log("Parsed query params:", parsed.queryParams);
   
    if (parsed.path && parsed.path.startsWith("updatepassword")) {     
      const token = parsed.path.split("/").pop();

      navigationRef.current?.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{ name: "UpdatePassword", params: { token } }],
      });
      console.log("Navigating to UpdatePassword screen with token:", token);
    } else {
      console.log("Path does not match updatepassword pattern.");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleInitialURL = async () => {
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      if (url) {
        console.log("Initial URL:", url);
        handleDeepLink({ url });
      }
    };

    Linking.addEventListener("url", handleDeepLink);
    handleInitialURL();
    // Comment out removeEventListener if not supported
    return () => {
      // Linking.removeEventListener("url", handleDeepLink);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}
      ref={navigationRef}
      fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}
    >
      <AuthProvider>
        <MainDrawerNavigation />
        <FlashMessage position="bottom" />
      </AuthProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;

Console Logs:
 handleDeepLink myapp://updatepassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFuZ2UucGluY2hvbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwc2V1ZG8iOiJBbmdlbG91IiwiZXhwIjoxNzIyODYwMzQ1LCJpYXQiOjE3MjI4NTY3NDV9.jIoW-hvLVTGEcAS41496097JkDwuc9VIQ060guol060
c2V1ZG8iOiJBbmdlbG91IiwiZXhwIjoxNzIyODYwMzQ1LCJpYXQiOjE3MjI4NTY3NDV9.jIoW-hvLVTGEcAS41496097JkDwuc9VIQ060guol060
 LOG  Parsed path: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFuZ2UucGluY2hvbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwc2V1ZG8iOiJBbmdlbG91IiwiZXhwIjoxNzIyODYwMzQ1LCJpYXQiOjE3MjI4NTY3NDV9.jIoW-hvLVTGEcAS41496097JkDwuc9VIQ060guol060
 LOG  Parsed query params: {}
 LOG  Path does not match updatepassword pattern.


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
